# ssh: terminal problem when executing command on remote server

Tags: ssh, terminal

I have a local script, and I need to start a service on a remote server.

Normally, if I was logged in on the remote server, I would use for example:

```
service rsyslog restart
```

and I would see following output:

[image]

But when I connect non-interactively from my script, ie

```
ssh myserver.com "service rsyslog restart"
```

I don't get the colorized `[OK]` output:

[image]

And when I add `-t` option to `ssh`, I do get the colorized output, but then also I get extra verbose info `Connection to server closed.` which i don't want because it interferes with my script:

[image]

How can I get colorized output without the extra verbose info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you also add on the `-q`(uiet) option, it will suppress the disconnect line and other information messages:

```
ssh -tq myserver.com "service rsyslog restart"
```

> ```
>  -q      Quiet mode.  Causes most warning and diagnostic messages to be suppressed.
> ```